# Perl printing out ascii test with chr()

Tags: perl

On this simple program, how can I put a comma between each entity, but leave it off and the end ?

```
$ cat  array_maker.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my @total = @ARGV ;
my $d_quote = chr(34);
my $comma = chr(44);


foreach my $total(@total) {
     print " $d_quote$total$d_quote$comma" ;
}
```

I get this:

```
$ ./array_maker.pl one two three four
"one", "two", "three", "four",
```

I want this:

```
"one", "two", "three", "four" #no comma at end of string.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interative way is:

```
for (my $i=0;$i<scalar(@total);$i++)
{
    print $d_quote . $total[$i] . $d_quote;
    if ($i != (scalar(@total) - 1)) { print $comma; }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a knack for over complicating things! `for (my $i=0;$i<scalar(@total);$i++)` is better written as `for my $i (0..$#total)`, and `(scalar(@total) - 1)` is better written as `@total - 1` or just `$#total`. Also, it's far simpler to print the comma at the start of the loop (`if $i > 0`) than at the end (`if $i < $#total`).

Comment: A noob isn't likely to understand any of that without looking up even more things.

Comment: What are you talking about??? Look again! Not only does it not use any more more things than yours, the thing it does use are far more useful and basic. I don't think I've ever used C-style `for` or `scalar(@a)`; teaching these rarely useful and complicated structures over those used daily is not a good thing! Especially when it results in such unreadable code!

Comment: @SectoKia  (1) The C-style `for` loop is almost never needed in Perl -- and yours cannot even be compared with `for (0..$#total)`. (2) Btw, the `scalar` isn't needed there -- `$i < @total` does it, and is far clearer. (3) How is your condition clearer than `if $i > 0` at the beginning? //   This is really not Perl code.

Comment: @SectoKia    As for "_noob_" understanding -- if people learn C, they should learn the C-way of doing it -- if it's C++ you don't advise them to write C -- if it's Perl they should be learning Perl ways and idioms -- if it's Python ... etc. If somebody is going to work with a kitchen knife they shouldn't be learning how to use a hunting knife.  They'll end up hurting themselves.  In programming, when we pick up new tools we learn its ways and idioms from the beginning. It pays off very quickly. All this is intended to be informative, not critical.

Comment: Secto Kia gave me what I needed  - the C style is the easiest to understand.. You need to crawl before you walk, you need to understand c style loop before moving to map or join.  if it were not useful than the perl founder would not allow for a multiplicity of ways to do it

Comment: @capser  That's great that you like this, and clear by your response, and nobody questions that. However: I suggest that instead of "_understanding_" C-style code you learn Perl, if you are using Perl.  This is a poor translation of C (no offense meant -- but it is) and that is not a way to write any language.  Don't have to crawl over broken glass.  Just my best intentions ...

Comment: yes - Secto Kia looked at my script, judged my level of skill, and then wrote an answer to target my level of skill. he was right on.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the array index instead, and add the comma `unless $i == $#array;`.

But here is another way

```
print join $comma, map { "$d_quote$_$d_quote" } @total;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's far easier to print the comma at the start of the loop (when necessary) than at the end.

```
for my $i (0..$#total) {
    print "," if $i > 0;
    print qq{"$total[$i]"};
}

print("\n");
```

I wouldn't recommend this the following, but it shows you don't actually need the indexes:

```
for (@total) {
    print "," if \$_ != \$total[0];
    print qq{"$_"};
}

print("\n");
```

But `join` works far better.

```
print(join(",", map { qq{"$_"} } @total), "\n");
```

Finally, it looks like you are generating CSV. You should really be using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS) for that!

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });

$csv->say(\*STDOUT, \@total);
```

Quotes will be added where necessary, and escapes will be used where necessary.

Comment: this is very consicise - I wish i could just write code like this : for my $i (0..$#total) {
    print "," if $i > 0;
    print qq{"$total[$i]"};

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
print $d_quote . join("$d_quote$comma$d_quote", @total) . $d_quote;
```